# Finding html element onPreRender state of User Control

Tags: asp.net, html, user-controls, prerender

I have a user control which has html elements like `<input type="button"....` and i want to set its display property on preRender state.

Would you please explain, what kind things i have to handle this user control? So, in this function
`protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) { }`
I have only `EventArgs e` and it doesn't have proper method or properties to bring me the html of user control.

Thank you from now...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to control visibility of elements from the server side is to promote them to server controls. For example:

```
<input id="mybutton" runat="server" type="button" ...
```

Doing so would allow you to execute a statement like the following in your `OnPreRender()` event:

```
mybutton.Visible = false; // removes the element
```

Or...

```
mybutton.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display] = "none"; // styles the element
```

Comment: Yes you are right. It is easiest way. But i need to access its html code. I will delete or add something before it is posting to client.